# RDP: replace remote host's desktop with local desktop

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, desktop

When I connect to a remote host via RDP, my local folders and drives are available on the RDP session under the `\\tsclient` connection, so that, if I for instance want to access a file that resides on my desktop I need to go under `\\tsclient`, `C:`, `users`, `myusername`, and `Desktop` which takes an 5 additional steps.

**Question: is it possible to have my desktop set as the remote host's desktop?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be something out there, but I really don't think so. You could create a shortcut to your desktop and put it in the root of \tsclient to shorten the process.

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can create shortcuts on the remote desktop to the folders and files on your host desktop.